# disable click on certain area with a transparency picture or javascript better?

Tags: javascript, css, web, click

I have one of the area that I don't want to be click at all on my site but just can see

let say its a video so I will only allow them to use the control player but not using the play/pause by clicking on the video like what youtube or any other website does.

I have an idea of using transparent photo to overlap the area that I wish not to be click

but fail because the css I use I can never succeed to get it exact place.

so I wish to know if there is a way either by css or javascript to stop the user to click on the area I want?

Thanks

Comment: it gets tricky with flash content because in a lot of browsers anything flash will automatically be on top no matter what `z-index`'s you assign

Comment: @iliacholy that is sucks because I have embed code from one of the site and they make a very annoying video embed behaviour of whenever someone click on the video [not the control part] it will go to their site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this cross-browser is using an iframe shim. Iframes can sit on top of flash content unlike other elements.

```
<iframe width="70%" height="500px" name="about" src="about.html" frameborder=0 ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"></iframe>
```

src: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1253/htmlcss-transparent-iframes-in-all-browsers/

You might need to use filters in ie to make it transparent

```
iframe.style.filter='progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0,opacity=0)';
```

src: http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html